# Convexity of discrete Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, convexity

Let $f : [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous convex function on $(0,2\pi)$ which is singular about $0$ and $2\pi$ but finite when evaluated at the boundaries. Assume also that $f$ is symmetric about $\pi$. The *discrete Fourier transform* of $f$ when sampled at $2\pi i/N$ is then given by
$$
X_n := \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n i}{N}\right)f\left(\frac{2\pi i}{N}\right), \quad n = 1,\ldots,N-1.
$$

> **Question:** Given the convexity of $f$, does there exist a convex function $G : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $G(n/N) = X_n$? That is, when the DFT is plotted against $n = 1,\ldots,N-1$, does it agree with a convex function. Is the DFT a discrete convex function with respect to $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, there need not exist a convex function $G$ such that $X_n = G(n/N)$. For instance, let $N=6$ and $f(x)\equiv\lvert x-\pi\rvert$ (your condition that $f$ be singular near $0$ and $2\pi$ is inessential, since the summand for $i=0$ in the expression for $X_n$ does not depend on $n$, whereas the values of the other summands there do not depend on values of $f$ very near $0$ or $2\pi$.) Then
$$X_n=\frac{1}{3} \pi  \left(2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{3}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  n}{3}\right)+\cos
   \left(\frac{4 \pi  n}{3}\right)+2 \cos \left(\frac{5 \pi  n}{3}\right)+3\right),$$
which is not convex in $n$, as seen from this (connected) graph $\{(n,X_n)\colon n=1,\dotsc,5\}$:

[image: Graph of (n, X_n) for n = 1, …, 5]

More specifically, here $X_2=X_4=0$ and $X_3=\pi/3$, so that $X_3\not\le(X_2+X_4)/2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that makes sense. Would you know what conditions of $f$ are necessary for the  DFT output to be convex?

Comment: @Orbital : I don't know such necessary conditions right away. I think it would be better in more ways than one to ask such additional questions in separate posts.

Comment: Thank you for your help though, much appreciated. I shall ask an additional question.